# No AVD Available for Flutter Android Studio Project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to learn *Flutter* so following the getting started guides and hit a hurdle pretty much straight away, and so far what I've found on Google doesn't seem related to my issue.

I have installed the *Flutter* plugins for *Android Studio* and created a new *Flutter* application project. *Android Studio* loads the project fine but I can't run it as it says there are no devices available except for *Edge* or *Chrome* instead of an AVD (*Android Virtual Device*) being listed.

Below is what I see on the toolbar of *Android Studio*.

[image: Android Studio Toolbar]

Below is what I get when select the drop down for "No Device Selected"

[image: Device Selection Dropdown]

Below are the AVDs that I have should have available from the AVD Manager

[image: AVD List]

I've run the `flutter doctor` command followed by the `flutter devices` command which has the following output

[image: Flutter doctor and flutter devices output]

*Android Studio* and the *Android SDK* is fully up to date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure *Android SDK* using *Project Structure* settings:

[image]

Now *Android Emulator(s)* should be available from the *Devices* dropdown menu:

[image]